# Transformation to normality for random variables with different locations

Tags: data-transformation, normalization, normality-assumption

I have a (potentially infinite) sequence of random variables $X_i$, with $i = 1, 2, \dots$, which have the same distribution (in terms of "shape"), but different locations.

I have a sample of size $N$ from only one of these distributions and I would like to find a transformation to normality that works for the whole sequence of distributions. The locations are all unknown as well the analytic form of true distributions. All I have is a sample from one element of the sequence.

Notice that I need a transformation that uses the same parameters for every distribution. For example if, give my initial sample, I decide to use the Box-Cox($\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$) transform, when I get a new sample I have to transform it using exactly the same transform (otherwise I would simply shift each sample to zero).

So far I haven't found anything that works: Box-Cox requires positivity of the sample (the shifting parameter doesn't help because the location varies from sample to sample). Similar problem for the Inverse Hyperbolic Sine transform.

Any suggestion is welcome!

EDIT:

This problem arises from an application where I have a data $y_1, \dots, y_n$, generated by a stochastic model $m(\theta_0)$, where $\theta_0$ is an unknown parameter.

I'm trying to estimate $\theta_0$ by Maximum Likelihood. At each step $k$ of the optimization I'm simulating a sample $x_1, \dots, x_n$ from the model $m(\theta_k)$, and I rely on the sample being approximately normally distributed to estimate the likelihood. Unfortunately the sample often has departures from normality, which is why I'm interested in transformations. I need to use exactly the same transformation across the parameters space in order to compute the likelihood correctly. For different $\theta$s the mean of the sample changes, but shape of the distribution seems to be fairly constant.

Comment: You lost me at the second paragraph: there cannot exist a single way of re-expressing the values that will make all these random variables Normal unless all the $\mu_i$ are equal or they were all Normal to begin with.  Perhaps it would help if you could explain why you are looking for such a transformation.

Comment: I should have concluded my question with "I think this is impossible" but I wanted to sound more positive. :)
I'll edit the question to give some detail about why I have this problem.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what is assumed known vs. unknown. You state in the 2nd paragraph that we don't know the parameter or the analytic form of the distribution. However, MLE is usually a parametric technique, so some form is assumed. There are non-parametric MLE approaches, such as emipirical likelihood, boostrap MLE, estimating equations, etc. But it sounds like you are using the usual MLE, in which case you should have some idea of the parametric model underlying the data, which you seem know given your last sentence. Are you assuming X is a member of the location-scale family?

Comment: @Eupraxis I don't know the true distribution of $X$, but I hope that it is not too far from normal, because I'm using the a normal approximation to estimate the likelihood. In many cases I know that the distribution of $X$ is asymptotically normal, but my sample sizes are quite small so there are departures from normality. In particular skewness is the main problem I would like to correct by using a transformation. I don't assume that X is a member of the location-scale family, but I noticed that often the location of X changes rapidly with $\theta$, will higher moments more slowly.